# Position dynamic textarea exactly over existing box element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box element (actually an `<ol>` with some `<li>`s) and I want to create a textarea exactly over it, so the list will be editable.

The translation functions (items->text; then parse back text->items) are already done (for the second part, all the `<li>`s are removed and recreated from the text).

But I don't know how to position this textarea to be **exactly** over the list.

**Edit:**

Here is some code:

```
<h2>TODO List</h2>
<div id="container">
    <ol id="theol" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left: 15px; width: 270px; border: 1px solid Gray;">
        <li><span>Locate the ol element</span></li>
        <li><span>Add the text input after it</span></li>
        <li><span>Change text input style to position it over the &lt;ol&gt;</span></li>
        <li><span>Capture ENTER or ESC (maybe blur() too)</span></li>
        <li><span>If ESC then just abandon everything</span></li>
        <li><span>If ENTER (or blur()) then clear all the &lt;li&gt; and recreate them</span></li>
        <li><span>Get rid of input</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- injected script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theol = $('ol#theol');
    var newlist = $('<textarea/>').insertAfter(theol);
    // how to position 'newlist' exactly over 'theol'?
</script>
```

The trick is: the script is injected (via bookmarklet) and I don't have control of the pre-existing data. Also, the style maybe not static like above (margin, padding, width). I don't know yet, but I think it's height is variable (adjust to contents).

Comment: unable to understand. can you add something like an image?

Comment: Add your code buddy... Only then we can help, or put up a JSFiddle...

Comment: I'll try to come up with a small code. Come back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a contaning element like:

```
<div class="containingelement">
   <ul>
   </ul>
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

and set positions and z-indexes like:

```
.containingelement{
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}

.containingelement textarea{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

and make sure width and height match

Comment: "width and height match" to what? The `ul` element? Is there a way to get its dimensions in javascript? I'm augmenting a 3rd party site, so I don't have control of its style.

Comment: It worked! Had the textarea `width` and `height` set to 100%. `position: relative` on the parent is absolutely necessary (it was previously set to `static`; I managed to save the setting before with `$(...).css('position')` and restore it afterwards). `z-index: 1` was not necessary on the parent; I don't know whether that element already had it set. Thanks a lot.